# Image upload from node js server to PHP server

Tags: php, node.js

I have a image saved on my node server. I need to send this image to API written in PHP. The api accepts file from php's $_FILES.

How can i send the file from node to PHP API so that it can read from $_FILES.

i am using npm **request package** for sending requests

Comment: The documentation has an example: [Sending forms](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#forms)

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like the following perhaps:

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

var data = {
  file: fs.createReadStream( '/path/to/my/image.jpg' )
};
request.post({ url:'http://example.com/upload.php', formData:data }, function callback( err, response, body ) {
    if( err ) {
        return console.error( 'Failed to upload:', err );
    }
    console.log( 'Upload successful!' );
});
```

Or, to create a page that allows the user to select the photo to upload

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

  res.write('<form action="http://example.com/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
  res.write('<input type="file" name="usrfile" />');
  res.write('<input type="submit" />');
  res.write('</form>');

  return res.end();
}).listen(8088);
```

On the PHP server to handle the upload you could do this:

```
<?php
    /* node.js upload target ~ "upload.php" */
    if( isset( $_FILES ) ){

        /* change path to suit environment */
        $dir='c:/temp/fileuploads/1/';

        $obj=(object)$_FILES['file'];
        $name=$obj->name;
        $tmp=$obj->tmp_name;

        $result = move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $dir.$name );
        echo $result ? 'File '.$name.' ws moved to '.$dir : 'Error: Failed to save '.$name;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks...this worked partially for me.The image is getting captured in $_FILES. But my code fails as move_uploaded_file always returns false. there are no errors. I think it has something to do with the fact that the file is not uploaded by php. is there a sol for this?